# Why font style doesn't work in external style sheet?

Tags: css

I'm define and using my custom font.In internal style sheet this worked fine but when I use it in external style sheet it does not work.
This is my code:

```
@font-face
 {
    font-family: A1Tahoma;
    src: url('Fonts/a1tahoma.eot') format('eot')
         , url('Fonts/a1tahoma.ttf') format('truetype')
         , url('Fonts/a1tahoma.woff') format('woff')
         , url('Fonts/a1tahoma.svg') format('svg'); 


   /* font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;*/
} 
  body,.test1 
{

 font-family:A1Tahoma; font-weight: bold;font-style: normal;

}  
<div class="test1">این خط را باید با نوع فونت تاهما ببینید<br />همچنین عدد 125420 به صورت فارسی تایپ شده است.</div>
```

Can you help me?
[image]

Comment: it's not working in all browser?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi yes,it's not worked in IE, Firefox,chorom ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

salam,baraye in kar ghable font ye / bezar yani injori va url ham bedon cot bezar

```
url(/Fonts/a1tahoma.eot) format('eot')
```

You can use this style for load font

```
url(/Fonts/a1tahoma.eot) format('eot')
```

Comment: in rahi ke goftamo anjam bedin be javab miresin hamid jan

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is related to your relative URLs in the stylesheet.  Is the external stylesheet in the same location as your html page?  The paths in the url('Fonts/...') must work from the location of the CSS.  For example, if you have the following structure:

```
index.html
Fonts/a1tahoma.eot
css/styles.css
```

Then you need to change the URL to be `src: url('../Fonts/a1tahoma.eot')`

Comment: yea,I use them in same location and test your answer but it doesn't work yet!

Comment: I don't see the stylesheet in your screenshot - where is it?

Comment: @richard looking at the orignal code the styles are inline on the webpage.

Comment: I can see the inline styles.  Since my answer was about the location of the external style sheet, this is what I was referring to.  This is not shown in the screenshot of the project layout.  This is what the paths must be relative to.

Comment: @Richard ,The external path of styles are in App_Themes folder/DefaultTheme/main.css

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
font-family: 'A1Tahoma';
```

might because for ' '